# Efcore .net6 Applying global query filters while dynamically selecting entity inside condition based on data from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

i'm trying to use Query filters in .net 6 app and for the most part it's working except this use case.

I Have multiple ways to filter tableB based on what is in table A but one of them is if they have different characteristics but the the characteristics they have point to the same Table and same value.
[image]

```cs
!TableA.Characteristic.IsTableBased && !TableB.Characteristic.IsTableBased
             && TableA.Characteristic.TableName == TableB.Characteristic.TableName
             && TableA.RecordId == TableB.RecordId
             && this.Set<BaseEntity<int>>(TableA.Characteristic.TableName).First(x => x.Id == gradeCharacteristic.RecordId).!IsExpired
```

The thing that's not working is referencing the proper entity inside the global query filter based on the table name inside characteristic table.

Any help please?

Using .FromSqlRaw, reflection, Set(entityName)

Comment: Which exception do you have?

Comment: Basically that the expression could not be translated to Expression tree...

Comment: Looking closer at your filter... It is not possible with EF Core or even with raw SQL.

Comment: Is that because of the way i'm writing the code or hole concept in general ? Meaning having a table name as a record along with the record Id in that table..

Comment: Yes, you cannot create query which select from different tables based on record value.